# trying to pass text from tableview to a view with a map

Tags: ios, uitableview, dictionary, title

I have a UITableView that opens a view with a map, i called Mapa class. I am having problems passing any kind of text information from this table view to the map. I need to send a string text to be the title of my map, and the coordinates of a CLLocation.

Here is part of the code

MyTableView.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    instMapa = [[Mapa alloc] initWithNibName:@"Mapa" bundle:nil];
    instMapa.mytext = @"pass text to be the title";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:instMapa animated:YES];

}
```

Mapa.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>

@class MapViewAnnotation;

@interface Mapa : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;


    NSString *stringTitle;

    NSString *mytext;

    MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation;



}

@property (nonatomic, retain)   IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSString *stringTitle;

@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSString *mytext;

@property (nonatomic, retain)   MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation;


@end
```

Mapa.m

```
#import "Mapa.h"
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"


@implementation Mapa

@synthesize mapView;

@synthesize stringTitle;

@synthesize mytext;

@synthesize newAnnotation;




// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];




    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;


    location.latitude = (double) 51.501468;
    location.longitude = (double) -0.141596;



    // Add the annotation to our map view
    newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:mytext andCoordinate:location];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];



}

// When a map annotation point is added, zoom to it (1500 range)
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 1500, 1500);
    [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [mv selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];
}

// Received memory warning
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

// If the view unloads, release the map view
- (void)viewDidUnload {

}

- (void)dealloc {

    [newAnnotation release];

    [mytext release];

    [stringTitle release];

    [mapView release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

MapViewAnnotation.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface MapViewAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    NSString *title;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d;


@end
```

MapViewAnnotation.m

```
@implementation MapViewAnnotation

@synthesize title, coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
    [super init];
    title = ttl;
    coordinate = c2d;
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [title release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What happens exactly when you select a row?  Does it crash?  If it crashes, what is the exact crash message?

Comment: One potential problem is in the `initWithTitle` method in MapViewAnnotation.  The line `title = ttl;` should be `title = [ttl copy];` to make sure that value stays even if `mytext` is later released.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understand that; you need to pass the string value of the selected table view cell to your map view.
For that you need to write this code in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`,

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 instMapa.mytext = cell.textLabel.text;
```

Comment: thank you for the fast answer. But it is not working, the problem is that i can't pass any kind of argument, like a string, from my tableview to the instance of Mapa, with my map.

Comment: can you please add this line  instMapa.mytext = [[NSString alloc]init]; before instMapa.mytext = @"pass text to be the title"; and tell me what happens.

Comment: Did you put NSLog for the mytext in the viewDidLoad ?

Comment: yes. The problem must be with my tabbar. I tried to pass arguments with other classes too and it is not working.